# Adding AdMob banners with Apportable starter SDK

Tags: java, android, apportable

I have been trying to integrate AdMob into my cocos2d game which i have ported to android using apportable.

I have integrated the GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar into my project and set up a bridge to the java code that will load the ads.

#### Java to load ad

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
    
   // Create the adView
   adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "MY_AD_UNIT_ID");
            
   // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it's been given
   // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
   LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    
   // Add the adView to it
   layout.addView(adView);
    
   // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
   adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
}
```

This works and it loads an advert on screen.

The problem i am having is that it displays the advert on a white view that takes up the entire screen.

[image: White Screen]

I have tried multiple ways of getting the current view and adding the banner to that but every method i have tried ether does not work or it displays the white view.

Does anyone know of a solution to my problem?? any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Hello, are you able to click the AdView OK? I have succesfully added the Banner View on top with my game showing but it is not clickable ...

Comment: Hi, I'm now using SpriteBuilder 1.3 beta. I try to add admob ads into project using BridgeKit but it's not working,can you send me a demo like above?